# how to show google ad in flash cs6?

Tags: flash

I used this code and ANE file   in library path but ad didn't show please help me.?

http://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android/ (
Old link > http://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios/)

I take ANE file above link

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

import so.cuo.platform.admob.Admob;
import so.cuo.platform.admob.AdmobPosition;


function SimpleDemo()
{

    var admob:Admob = Admob.getInstance();
    trace(admob.supportDevice)
    if (admob.supportDevice)
    {
        admob.setKeys("k9c0d6c840db6180439d2e7add2bf014");
        admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    }
    else
    {
    txt.text=" Device not support"

    }
}
SimpleDemo()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Also make sure you are using air sdk 4.0

Answer (score 0):

1.replace the admob id with your self admob ID

2.change SimpleDemo()  to new SimpleDemo()

3.config the xxx-app.xml